# Bash reverse logic in a double while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have this list of objects called vs-hosts-objects.txt, derived from a Cisco ASA config. The list describes hostnames, their ip-adddress and their NAT-address.
Example:

```
object network net01 subnet 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
object network SRV002 host 172.16.0.2
object network SRV003 host 172.16.0.3
object network VPN-Pool range 172.17.100.200 172.17.100.230
object network SRV003 (internal,int-Internet) static 87.88.89.90
object network SRV012 host 172.16.0.12
object network SRV012 (internal,int-Internet) static 87.88.89.91
object network SRV013 host 172.16.0.13
```

Some have NAT-addresses attached, some don't. I need to process this list to be able to import a list into a new firewall (new vendor) and document this IP's used for hosts in our IPAM (so no subnets or ranges at this time).
For this I need it output like this:

```
SRV003,172.16.0.3,87.88.89.90
SRV012,172.16.0.12,87.88.89.91
SRV013,172.16.0.13
```

I have created this snippet, which works for getting the hosts that has a NAT-address:

```
while read -r line
 do 
 hostobj=`echo $line | grep host | awk  '{ print $3 }'`
 hostipobj=`echo $line | grep host | awk  '{ print $5 }'`
 while read -r staticline
  do
  natobj=`echo $staticline | grep static | awk  '{ print $3 }'`
  natipobj=`echo $staticline | grep static | awk  '{ print $6 }'`
  if [ "$natobj" != "" ];
   then
    if [ "$hostobj" = "$natobj" ];
     then
      echo "$hostobj,$hostipobj,$natipobj"
    fi
  fi
 done < vs-hosts-objects.txt
done < vs-hosts-objects.txt
```

But I can for the life of me, not figure out how to get the hosts, that does NOT have a NAT address attached, listed.
Although I am sure there are smarter, better and faster ways of doing this, I am not opposed to running another snippet for the hosts without NAT attached. All my attempts to get that result have ended in failure.
Hoping for help and wish you the best of days!
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `host` line always comes before the NAT line, you can populate an associative array with the IPs like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
declare -A ips
while read -ra columns ; do
    name=${columns[2]}
    if [[ ${columns[3]} == host ]] ; then
        ips[$name]=${columns[4]}
    elif [[ ${columns[4]} == static ]] ; then
        ips[$name]+=",${columns[5]}"
    fi
done < vs-hosts-objects.txt

for name in "${!ips[@]}" ; do
    echo "$name,${ips[$name]}"
done
```

If not, you can use two separate associative arrays, one for each type.

Comment: This is awesome! Minor thing, how do I get a comma inserted before the NAT-address? I figured I could just do something like `echo "$name,${ips[','$name]}"` but that did not work. :(
Guess I just don't quite understand the logic in this yet.

Comment: @IanS. go line 8 and use `ips[$name]+=",${columns[5]}"`